# Samsung Galaxy S3 notification bar style changes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-bar

I currently have Android 4.1.2 on my galaxy s3 from Verizon and I am having issues with the notification bar. Seemingly at random it changes how the notification bar works. I had recently updated the gmail app to allow messages to be archived from the notification bar. However later the bar changed back to the old style where it no longer showed snippets of the email in the notification bar and I can no longer take actions for new email. At the same time I noticed new notifications are tacked on to the right side of the list instead of the left side when the new features where working.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or figured out a solution for it?

This is still happening after I upgraded to Android 4.3

Comment: Do you have more than one email (or other) notification listed? This seems to _compact_ the notifications, so you don't necessarily get the options, unless you tap one of the notifications to expand it.

Comment: Before the change happened I could see the snippet text and actions for the top email notification as long as it was the only new email but now I never see it. If its just one email now I am just seeing the subject without all the extra features.

Comment: Randomly just switched back to the newer style of notifications and I am able to see snippets of email and respond/archive them from the notification bar again. Noticed it when all of a sudden new email notifications where appearing on the far right of the notification bar again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't find the answer anywhere.  Via the technique, commonly known as 'mucking about with my phone', I found that the new actions can be revealed by swiping down on the notification with two fingers. Likewise they can be hidden again by swiping upwards with two fingers.

Comment: I believe you can drag down with just one finger.

Comment: The issue I am having isn't that they are hidden but that the notification style for emails and other messages has completely reverted to an older style where the new features are not available.

Answer (score -2):

Do a restart. That fixed mine when I had the same issue

Comment: I have restarted my phone multiple times due to battery drain issues and the notification bar is still reverted to an earlier state.